# My page is breaking when url params contains '@' symbol in it in angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras, angular1.6

I'm using angular 1.6, my page is breaking whenever the url params has '@' symbol in it. 
For example, 
     www.stackoverflow.com?email=jon@gmail.com.
Not sure what is going on. It is encoding and working with all other symbols. I'm using ui-router, will that be any cause by chance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to urlencode the query string to avoid issues with special characters. Have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks. But I had more than 20 urls with '@', i don't want to urlencode everywhere. Is there any chance i can do it main js file.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean without seeing your code